# How to make two Laravel Eloquent queries into a single one (so I hit the database once instead of 2 times)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Say I have 3 tables in my database.

'my_recipe', 'my_inventory' and 'ingredient'.

The 'my_recipe' table stores a list of raw_id's based on the 'ingredient' table and the 'quantity' need for the recipe. The 'my_inventory' table stores a list of raw_id's and 'have_quantity'.

So let's take a look at what I currently have at the moment. I have the following 2 queries:

First Query:

```
$recipe = DB::table('my_recipe as tA')
    ->leftJoin('ingredient as tB', 'tA.raw_id', '=', 'tB.raw_id')
    ->select('tA.user as user', 'tA.raw_id as raw_id', 'tA.quantity as quantity',
        'tB.ingredient_name as ingredient_name')
    ->where('user', '=', $user)
    ->where('raw_id', '=', $raw_id)
    ->get();
```

Second Query:

```
$inventory = DB::table('my_inventory as tA')
    ->leftJoin('ingredient as tB', 'tA.raw_id', '=', 'tB.raw_id')
    ->select('tA.user as user', 'tA.have_quantity as have_quantity',
        'tB.ingredient_name as ingredient_name')
    ->where('user', '=', $user)
    ->get();
```

The first query returns results that look something like this:

```
{"user":"jack","raw_id":"853","quantity":2,"ingredient_name":"apple"},
{"user":"jack","raw_id":"853","quantity":4,"ingredient_name":"peach"}
```

The second query returns results that look something like this:

```
{"user":"jack","have_quantity":30,"ingredient_name":"apple"},
{"user":"jack","have_quantity":20,"ingredient_name":"apple"},
{"user":"jack","have_quantity":10,"ingredient_name":"apple"},
{"user":"jack","have_quantity":1,"ingredient_name":"peach"},
{"user":"jack","have_quantity":1,"ingredient_name":"peach"}
```

Notice in the second query results I have to get the sum of the ingredients based on the 'ingredient_name' for my ideal output.

How can I get my ideal output in a single query?

My ideal output would look something like this:

```
{"user":"jack","raw_id":"853","quantity":2,"ingredient_name":"apple","have_quantity":60},
{"user":"jack","raw_id":"853","quantity":4,"ingredient_name":"peach","have_quantity":2}
```

It's basically the results of the first query with 'have_quantity' totals from the second query.

EDIT:

my_recipe Model:

```
'user', 'raw_id', 'quantity'
```

my_inventory Model:

```
'user', 'raw_id', 'have_quantity'
```

ingredient Model:

```
'raw_id', 'ingredient_name'
```

Note: In the ingredient model there can be rows with the same 'ingredient_name' but have different 'raw_id'.

Comment: Can you write your eloquent models relations?

Comment: @G.Baghashvili: I added the Models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our chat conversation I managed to get some extra information on the table structure and what was needed to do to get the wanted results.

For those interested the information can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f6d126/4/0)

Anyway I ended up creating the query like this:

```
SELECT 
    my_recipe.user AS user,
    my_recipe.raw_id AS raw_id,
    my_recipe.quantity AS quantity,
    ingredient.ingredient_name AS ingredient_name,
    IFNULL(SUM(my_inventory.have_quantity),0) AS have_quantity
FROM my_recipe
LEFT JOIN ingredient USING(raw_id)
LEFT JOIN ingredient AS ingredients USING(ingredient_name)
LEFT JOIN my_inventory ON my_inventory.raw_id = ingredients.raw_id
WHERE my_recipe.recipe_id = 853 
AND my_recipe.user = 'jack'
AND my_inventory.user = 'jack'
GROUP BY ingredient_name;
```

Now converting into the needed structure:

```
$inventory = DB::table('my_recipe')
    ->leftJoin('ingredient', 'my_recipe.raw_id', '=', 'ingredient.raw_id')
    ->leftJoin('ingredient AS ingredients', 'ingredient.ingredient_name', '=', 'ingredients.ingredient_name')
    ->leftJoin('my_inventory', 'my_inventory.raw_id', '=', 'ingredients.raw_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('my_recipe.user AS user,my_recipe.raw_id AS raw_id,my_recipe.quantity AS quantity,ingredient.ingredient_name AS ingredient_name,IFNULL(SUM(my_inventory.have_quantity),0) AS have_quantity'))
    ->where('my_recipe.recipe_id', '=', $recipe_id)
    ->where('my_recipe.user', '=', $user)
    ->where('my_inventory.user', '=', $user)
    ->groupBy('ingredient_name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: quantity shows up as null when the inventory has more than 1 row of the same ingredient_name

Comment: Is there a way to use the one row that has a value in tC.quantity (as there will always only be 1 row that has a value) instead of another that shows as null?

Comment: I added the table structure Models to the question if that helps.

Comment: @rotaercz Sorry for that, `quantity` comes `tA => my_inventory` but should come from `tC => my_recipe`, updated the answer.

Comment: It's pretty close but quantity still shows as null.

Comment: I think ->leftJoin('my_recipe as tC', 'tC.raw_id', '=', 'tB.raw_id') should be based on ingredient_name rather than raw_id. How would I have to change the query to make it work that way since ingredient_name does not exist in the my_recipe table?

Comment: @rotaercz I've changed the answer as I took a wrong approach the first time :-)

Comment: I tried but I'm getting the error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tC.ingredient_name' in 'on clause' since the ingredient_name column doesn't exist for the my_inventory table. I think if you can just leftjoin (or join?) the my_inventory table ingredient_names to the my_inventory table it should work.

I tried removing the line causing the error on the off chance it would work and it runs but now the have_quantity comes out as null.

Comment: Mind sharing the exact table structure for all three tables?

Comment: It's in the question?

Comment: Basically I need to get the ingredient_name column from the ingredient table and apply it to both of the other tables. Then leftjoin those 2 tables based on the ingredient_name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159517/discussion-between-peter-m-and-rotaercz).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can solve you problem

```
//replace count by sum
$inventory = DB::table('my_inventory as tA')
        ->leftJoin('ingredient as tB', 'tA.raw_id', '=', 'tB.raw_id')
        ->leftJoin('my_recipe as tC', 'tC.raw_id', '=', 'tB.raw_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('tA.user as user, tB.ingredient_name as ingredient_name, SUM(tA.have_quantity) have_quantity'))
        ->where('user', '=', $user)
        ->groupBy('tB.ingredient_name, tA.user')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I tried your solution, I got an error with the groupBy and I need the 'quantity' too. I tried changing your groupBy to something like this: groupBy('tB.card_name', 'tA.username') and added the quantity but it gives me null for quantity. Also the 'have_quantity' shows an incorrect value.

Comment: Replace `COUNT(tA.have_quantity) have_quantity')` with `SUM(tA.have_quantity) as have_quantity')` to get the correct `have_quantity` value. I don't see the column names `card_name` and `username` in your question. Add correct column names in the question to get better assistance with your problem.

Comment: Oh, I meant groupBy('tB.ingredient_name, tA.user'). This was giving me an error so I changed it to groupBy('tB.ingredient_name', 'tA.user'). Changing it to SUM now provides the correct value for have_quantity but I still need 'quantity' which comes out as null

Comment: @rotaercz If you add a (non aggregated) column to the SELECT list, you probably also need to add it to the GROUP BY list. Otherwise you might get an error due to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode. In your case it should be `->groupBy('tB.ingredient_name, tA.user, tC.quantity')`. Or define proper UNIQUE keys, so the engine can determine functional dependency.

Comment: quantity shows up as null when the inventory has more than 1 row of the same ingredient_name. When I tried, ->groupBy('tB.ingredient_name', 'tA.user', 'tC.quantity') it shows the break down of the inventory which isn't what I want.

Comment: Is there a way to use the one row that has a value in tC.quantity (as there will always only be 1 row that has a value) instead of another that shows as null?

Comment: I added the table structure Models to the question if that helps.

Comment: @rotaercz Just use `SUM(tC.quantity) as quantity` then. If there is only one value in the group, then you will get exactly that value.

Comment: quantity is still showing up as null but there's definitely a value in the table in the database.

Comment: I think it's because the ->leftJoin('my_recipe as tC', 'tC.raw_id', '=', 'tB.raw_id') should probably be based on ingredient_name rather than raw_id but that column doesn't exist in that table. But I think there should be a way to still make this work without having to add it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
$result = DB::table('ingredient as ing')
    ->rightJoin('my_recipe as rcp', 'ing.raw_id', '=', 'rcp.raw_id')
    ->rightJoin('my_inventory as inv', 'ing.raw_id', '=', 'inv.raw_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('
        rcp.user as user, 
        ing.ingredient_name as ingredient_name, 
        rcp.have_quantity quantity, 
        SUM(inv.have_quantity) have_quantity
    '))
    ->where('rcp.user', '=', $user)
    ->where('rcp.raw_id', '=', $raw_id)
    ->groupBy('rcp.user, ing.ingredient_name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is only getting a single row. I need all the corresponding rows.

Comment: The values for the single row are all correct though.

Comment: @rotaercz Can you provide me example?

Comment: In the question I have an example of the ideal output. I'm only getting a single line rather than all the lines.